# Lambda Function: Understanding lambda function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

**CASE 1:**  ERROR output

```
def myfunc(n):
   return lambda a : a * n

mytripler(11) = myfunc(3)    => Error
```

===========================================

**CASE 2:**  Correct output

```
  def myfunc(n):
     return lambda a : a * n

  mytripler = myfunc(3)

  print(mytripler(11))
```

**How does the *value 11* get passed to the method in the second case?**

Comment: How is mytripler defined in the second case?

Comment: Case 1 does not make sense. You're trying to assign to the result of a function call. Of course that gives an error.

Comment: @Heike Edited. May you review the same.

Comment: @khelwood How 11 is assigned to variable 'a' here, when I mentioned, multiplier(11)?

Answer (score 0):

When myfunc is executed it is returning another function...

```
def myfunc(n):
    Return lambda x : x*n
```

Is same as  writing..

```
def myfunc(n):
    def f(x):
         Return x*n
    return f
```

Hence in first function you are returning another function and as it has formed closure it has access to n variable of parent function.

Comment: when I wrote multiplier(11), how did compiler understand that it should assign the value to variable "a"?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `myfunc` returns a function/callable (in this case lambda function), as can be seen here:

```
>>> def myfunc(n):
...    return lambda a : a * n
>>> print(myfunc)
<function myfunc at 0x7efe15c9dea0>
```

Now, when we make the call to `myfunc`, the value passed as `n` will be bound in the lambda function:

```
>>> mytripler = myfunc(3)
>>> print(mytripler)
<function myfunc.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7efe14f20598>
```

At this point `mytripler` is defined as `lambda a : a * 3`; the `n` was replaced by the value (or also: has been assgined the value) that we passed as argument to `myfunc()`. Note that this lambda construct is functionally equivalent to:

```
>>> def mytripler(a):
...     return a * 3
```

Now, we can call `mytripler` with an value to make the final calculation/execution:

```
>>> mytripler(11)
33
```

---

Your error is that you cannot assign a value to a function call on the left-hand side:

```
>>> mytripler(11) = myfunc(3)
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

But you can skip the intermediary step of assigning the result of `myfunc` to the name `mytripler`, and instead do both function calls chained together, like this:

```
>>> myfunc(3)(11)
33
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: when I wrote multiplier(11), how did compiler understand that it should assign the value to variable "a"?

Comment: @RudreshGt Python has an interpreter, not a compiler (small difference or big difference, depending on the point you are trying to make).

Comment: @RudreshGt I edited my answer. Is it clearer like that?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the way lambda functions work, the value 11 is used in place of the variable 'a' in your case and n is already 3.

When **mytripler = myfunc(3)** is ran, it is returning a function(lambda) which looks like

```
          def fun(a) : 
              return a * 3
```

Now the mytripler points to the above function "fun" which takes a single argument and multiplies it by 3.